# Как распарсить файл через <windows.h> MapViewOfFile?

Tags: c++

MapViewOfFile возвращает указатель на начало проекции куска большого текстового файла. А какие должны быть дальнейшие манипуляции, чтобы разобрать этот кусок по строкам? Как, например, представить его потоком и использовать while(std::getline(...))?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>



void ProcessChunk(LPVOID lpMapAddress, DWORD dwMapViewSize)
{
     // застрял тут.
}



bool ReadInChunks(const WCHAR *lpcTheFile)
{

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(
        lpcTheFile,                     //LPCSTR lpFileName,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,   //DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,                //DWORD dwShareMode,
        NULL,                           //LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
        OPEN_EXISTING,                  //DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,          //DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
        NULL                            //HANDLE hTemplateFile
    );

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        _tprintf(
            TEXT("hFile is NULL\n")
        );
        _tprintf(
            TEXT("Target file is %s\n"),
            lpcTheFile
        );

        system("pause");
        return false;
    }




    HANDLE hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
        hFile,                          //HANDLE hFile,
        NULL,                           //LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpFileMappingAttributes,
        PAGE_READWRITE,                 //DWORD flProtect,
        0,                              //DWORD dwMaximumSizeHigh,
        0,                              //DWORD dwMaximumSizeLow,
        NULL                            //LPCSTR lpName
    );

    if (hMapFile == NULL) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("hMapFile is NULL: last error: %d\n"), GetLastError());
        system("pause");
        return false;
    }




    SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo = { 0 };
    ::GetNativeSystemInfo(&sysinfo);
    DWORD dwSysGran = sysinfo.dwAllocationGranularity;


    LARGE_INTEGER file_size = { 0 };
    ::GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &file_size);
    const uint64_t dwFileSize = static_cast<uint64_t>(file_size.QuadPart);

    if (dwFileSize == NULL) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("dwFileSize is NULL: last error: %d\n"), GetLastError());
        system("pause");
        return false;
    }


    //Size of the file mapping view.
    DWORD dwMapViewSize = dwSysGran * 2;


    for (uint64_t offset = 0; offset < dwFileSize; offset += dwMapViewSize) {
        DWORD high = static_cast<DWORD>((offset >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFFul);
        DWORD low = static_cast<DWORD>(offset & 0xFFFFFFFFul);

        // The last view may be shorter.
        if (offset + dwMapViewSize > dwFileSize) {
            dwMapViewSize = dwFileSize - offset;
        }


        LPVOID lpMapAddress = MapViewOfFile(
            hMapFile,                       //HANDLE hFileMappingObject,
            FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,            //DWORD  dwDesiredAccess,
            high,                           //DWORD  dwFileOffsetHigh,
            low,                            //DWORD  dwFileOffsetLow,
            dwMapViewSize                   //SIZE_T dwNumberOfBytesToMap
        );

        if (lpMapAddress == NULL)
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("lpMapAddress is NULL: last error: %d\n"), GetLastError());
            system("pause");
            return false;
        }


        ProcessChunk(lpMapAddress, dwMapViewSize);
    }

}







int wmain(int argc, wchar_t** argv)
{

    ReadInChunks(argv[1]);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Зачем затрачивать усилия на маппинг файла, а потом сливать их оборачивая его в поток?

Comment: Сразу оговорюсь, что я не специалист, а этот вариант выбран исключительно для ознакомления. Цель - объединение несортированных текстовых файлов любого размера в 1 большой отсортированный. План был следующий: прочитать n-байт в буфер, отсортировать, совместить с итоговым файлом. + хотел посчитать скорость выполнения.